# Trying to run a query with OLEDBConnection Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, oledb, ado, oledbconnection

I get 1004 error on .Connection

```vb
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(ConnectionName).OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = MyCommandText
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .Connection = ConnectionString
```

ConnectionString looks like this:

```vb
"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" & Chr(59) & "Integrated Security=SSPI" & Chr(59) & _
"Persist Security Info=True" & Chr(59) & "Initial Catalog=wss_back" & Chr(59) & _
"Data Source=XX-X-0009999.de.xxx.com,12345" & Chr(59) & _
"Use Procedure for Prepare=1" & Chr(59) & "Auto Translate=True" & Chr(59) & _
"Packet Size=4096" & Chr(59) & "Workstation ID=XX-X-1234567" & Chr(59) & _
"Use Encryption for Data=False" & Chr(59) & _
"Tag with column collation when possible=False"
```

Any ideas why this fails?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```vb
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
```

CommandType expects a value from `ADODB.CommandTypeEnum`, but you are supplying a value from `xlCmdType`. `xlCmdSql` = 2, which is the same as `ADODB.adCommandTypeEnum.adCmdTable`, not `adCmdText`, which which is what you want here.

So change it to:

```vb
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(ConnectionName).OLEDBConnection
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .CommandText = MyCommandText
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .Connection = ConnectionString
```

...and it should work.